# Make [chrome-mobile] a synonym of [mobile-chrome]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The tag [chrome-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-mobile) should be a synonym of [mobile-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome).

They both refer to the mobile version of Google Chrome and the only difference is the order of the words.

- [mobile-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome) has more questions and has a description whereas [chrome-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-mobile) does not have a description.
- [mobile-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome) also has the same format as [mobile-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-safari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions tagged [chrome-mobile] does seem to be able to be re-tagged under [mobile-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome)

I have merged [chrome-mobile] into [mobile-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome) since there are only a handful of questions.

```
updating post history, 51 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 46 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 45 rows affected
destroying 'chrome-mobile': [chrome-mobile] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 160
tag remapping of [mobile-chrome] and [chrome-mobile] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym chrome-mobile -> mobile-chrome was approved!
```